# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'gerant' because 'gerant' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, foreach, public

hello i try to create an object named 'gerant'

```
 class gerant
{
    public double CIN_GERANT, NUM_TEL_GERANT, MOBILE_GERANT;
    public string NOM_GERANT, PRENOM_GERANT, ADRESSE__GERANT, MAIL_GERANT, VILLE_GERANT;
    public int CP_GERANT;
    public DateTime DATE_GERANT;

    public gerant(double _Cin_gerant, string _Nom_Gerant, string _Prenom_Gerant, string _Adresse_Gerant, double _Num_Tel_Gerant, string _Mail_Gerant, double _Mobile_Gerant, int _cp_gerant, string _ville_gerant, DateTime _date_gerant)
    {
        this.CIN_GERANT = _Cin_gerant;
        this.NOM_GERANT = _Nom_Gerant;
        this.PRENOM_GERANT = _Prenom_Gerant;
        this.ADRESSE__GERANT = _Adresse_Gerant;
        this.NUM_TEL_GERANT = _Num_Tel_Gerant;
        this.MAIL_GERANT = _Mail_Gerant;
        this.MOBILE_GERANT = _Mobile_Gerant;
        this.CP_GERANT = _cp_gerant;
        this.VILLE_GERANT = _ville_gerant;
        this.DATE_GERANT = _date_gerant;
    }

    public gerant getinfogerant()
    {
        gerant gerer = null;
        string sql_gerant = "select CIN,NOM,PRENOM,ADRESS_PERSONNEL,NUM_TEL,MAIL,MOBILE,CP_GERANT,VILLE_GERANT,DATE_CIN from GERANT";
        connexion connect = new connexion();
        OleDbConnection connection = connect.getconnexion();
        // try
        //{
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql_gerant, connection);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            gerer = new gerant(reader.GetDouble(0),
                reader.GetString(1),
                reader.GetString(2),
                reader.GetString(3),
            reader.GetDouble(4),
                reader.GetString(5),
                reader.GetDouble(6),
                reader.GetInt32(7),
                reader.GetString(8),
                reader.GetDateTime(9)
                );

        }
        connection.Close();
        return gerer;

    }
}
```

but when i try to fill my combobox with gerant i try to insert this code

```
 foreach(Modele.gerant ligne in liste_gerant)
        {

        }
```

but i make this error for me
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'gerant' because 'gerant' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

how can i resolve that?

Comment: What is `Modele.gerant`? Is it a class or a field? What is its type? What is `liste_gerant`? Is it a class or a field? What is its type?

Comment: How is `liste_gerant` defined?

Comment: Your `getinfogerant` is returning a single object, if that is what you're trying to use for the combobox dropdown.

Comment: You  need to implement the `IEnumerable` interface on liste_gerant. You need to post the definition of `liste_gerant` if you want us to help you.

Comment: Modele is a namespace where i insert the class gerant.

Comment: i define liste_gerant   Modele.gerant liste_gerant = new Modele.gerant().getinfogerant();

Comment: `getinfogerant` only returns a single item, not a list, so you can't iterate it. It doesn't make sense to, since its only one item, you don't need the for-each.

Comment: i try to insert an other exemple name 'modificateur' and i try to make a liste  of object public List<modificateur> getlignes(string table)
        {
            List < modificateur > listlignes= new List<modificateur>();
 and it works

Comment: it's means that must be return in a list or in table

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments. The gerant class is not a collection of any sort, and your getinfogerant doesn't return a collection.

So, the problem is that you are trying to iterate over a single value.

Answer (score 0):

From the query You use in getinfogerant I guess you want it to get all "gerant" in your db, not just one?

However now you're just returning the first. You should change its return type to List and turn the if (reader.Read()) into a while loop to fill the list, then return the whole list at the end.

Comment: yes exactly and this is how can i get all "gerant"   :                               public List<gerant> getinfogerant() { List<gerant> gerer = new List<gerant>();
             OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while(reader.Read()) { gerer.Add(new gerant(reader.GetDouble(0),reader.GetString(1),reader.GetString(2),
 reader.GetString(3),reader.GetDouble(4),                    reader.GetString(5),reader.GetDouble(6),                    reader.GetInt32(7), reader.GetString(8),                   reader.GetDateTime(9)) ); } return gerer; }

Comment: but how can  i add the first row in database as an default value appeared in combobox?

Comment: As I recall combo box has a selectedindex property you can set to 0, or otherwise a selectedvalue property you can set to the first item of your list.